# Sharing attributes between the same theme defined for different API levels

Tags: android, android-theme

I have a theme defined in values and values-v14.

Most of the attributes are the same (in values compared to values-v14), but some only appear in one and others only appear in the other.

How can I avoid duplication of attributes?

e.g. is it possible to import/include attributes?

How about setting up an intermediary Theme (defined in values) which includes all the common attributes. Then the actual theme would extend that...?

Answer (score 0):

You can create one parent theme and make the other two theme derive from it like:

```
<style name="Theme.ParentTheme">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.FirstTheme" parent="Theme.ParentTheme">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.InputMethod</item>
</style>
<style name="Theme.SecondTheme" parent="Theme.ParentTheme">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.OutputMethod</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, this is what I meant by an intermediary theme. Is this a standard approach?

Comment: Can you point me to an example where it specifically does this to support theme differences across multiple configurations (e.g. API levels)?